# How to find most common words in a MySQL database table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table in following format:

```
id | title
---+----------------------------
1  | php jobs, usa
3  | usa, php, jobs
4  | ca, mysql developer
5  | developer
```

i want to get the most popular keywords in title field, please guide.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title 1, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY title 1
```

**EDIT**

Since you've edited and presented a non-normalized table, I would recommend you normalize it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of keywords, you can do the following:

```
select kw.keyword, count(*)
from t cross join
     keywords kw
     on concat(', ', t.title, ',') like concat(', ', kw.keyword, ',')
```

As others have mentioned, though, you have a non-relational database design.  The keywords in the title should be stored in separate rows, rather than as a comma separated list.

If your data is small (a few hundred thousand rows or less), you can put it into Excel, use the text-to-columns function, rearrange the keywords, and create a new, better table in the database.

Comment: thank you very much it your comments help me a lot. i should save them to a new table with comma separated values.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of: http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your database.  You should have something like this:

```
items
+----+---------------+
| id | title         |
+----+---------------+
| 1  | something     |
| 3  | another thing |
| 4  | yet another   |
| 5  | one last one  |
+----+---------------+

keywords
+----+-----------------+
| id | keyword         |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | php jobs        |
| 2  | usa             |
| 3  | php             |
| 4  | jobs            |
| 5  | ca              |
| 6  | mysql developer |
| 7  | developer       |
+----+-----------------+

items_to_keywords
+---------+------------+
| item_id | keyword_id |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1          |
| 1       | 2          |
| 3       | 2          |
| 3       | 3          |
| 3       | 4          |
| 4       | 5          |
| 4       | 6          |
| 5       | 7          |
+---------+------------+
```

Do you see the advantage?  The ability to make relations is what you should be leveraging here.